# Different static fields from class and sublclasses

Tags: java

i'm newbie of Java, and my English is not so good... so excuse me in advance :)

I have a superclass: Genericresource with a static field that count how many instances are created, and a method to invoke this value:

```
public class Genericresource {
 private static int counter;
 public Genericresource() { counter++; }
 public static int howmany() { return counter; }
 //other useful code here
}
```

And i want to create some semi-identical subclasses, each for a specific resource:

```
public class Type1Resource extends Genericresource {

// here specific code

}
```

Now, in the main class:

```
Genericresource a1 = new Genericresource();
Genericresource a2 = new Genericresource();
Type1Resource b = new Type1Resource();
Type1Resource b2 = new Type1Resource();
int howa = Genericresource.howmany();
int howb = Type1Resource.howmany();
```

and i'm expecting that i'm using two different **counter** static fields, one for the superclass Genericresource, and one for the subclass Type1Resource.
My desired result is : howa = 2 howb = 2.
My real result is: howa 4 howb 4.

So i'm using the same *counter* static field even if i'm instantiate 2 different classes, while i need to
I need instead to refer at different counter static fields, one for each subclass, mantaining at the same time, the static methods structure of the superclass.
How can i do?

Answer (score 3):

Static variables pertain to the `class`, therefore the `counter` you are referencing in both `Genericresource` and `Type1Resource` is `Genericresource.counter` (through implicit parameter-less constructor invocation in child class), hence its value is `4` after two instances of each.

Declare a `static` counter in `Type1Resource`, and increment it in a specific `Type1Resource` constructor if you want to specifically count those instances only.

I suggest using a different name for the new counter as well, for clarity.

Comment: is right. If you still want to have that design, you should refactor to use another data structure like Map<Class,Counter>

Comment: @andresoviedo I agree... or a factory pattern.

Comment: The idea is to mantain an unique implementation of Genericresource with global operations about specific resources. My project is a boardgame framework (for to test my own boardgame betas), and i've imaged the class Genericresource for all typos of resources, with a static int field disponibility and a static int field total that count (if needing) the amount of generic tiles i have in the box, and GoldResource as sublclass for the "gold" tiles, with same static fields for to count specific use of the tiles. Sure i can rethink the data structure, but it was so elegant do all with static fields

Comment: I can provide specific fields into subclasses, but i have also to rewrite all the methods, losing the idea of inherit the class Genericstructure, with all the advantages it shows. Also, i can create a collection structure, but again, it means to rethink all data model. Well, if there isn't another solution i will scratch and restart.

Comment: @IdoTraini I'm afraid it may come to rethinking the data structure indeed. You should consider researching actual [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and even further, with creation patterns such as the [factory](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) or the [abstract factory](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm).